# opening and closing the keyboard removes a part of my webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

When I open the keyboard from touching the edittext in my toolbar above a WebView, and closing it with the back button, a part of my webview is gone and the background of my activity becomes visible ( white area where the keyboard was -> see second picture below the code). What's causing this and how can i fix it?

When i open and close the drawer that overlaps the webview while the empty area is visible, it somehow fills up the area with webpage content again like it should be.

The edittext is in the toolbar (not visible on the pictures, hides when scrolling)

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/toolbarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tmpBtn"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="#4d8cf3" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tmpBtn"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- Nav drawer -->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.fastbrowser.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

[image: keyboard shown]

[image: after backbutton pressed: white area (=activity background) where the keyboard was]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am curious.

Comment: Yup, adjustpan in manifest lol

Comment: Unfortunately this problem occurs for me on long scrollable forms.  Even `adjustPan` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This article gives a decent solution to this kind of problem - http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-keeping-buttons-visible.  The trick is to use weight for the ScrollView.

Comment: the adjustpan was the solution. I removed nestedscrollview because combining it with a WebView leads to several bugs.